# How can I enter these HDMI settings under Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, monitor, xrandr

The following monitor settings work in Ubuntu mate on a Raspberry Pi 2. How can I replicate these in Ubuntu Desktop 16.04? My Monitor is an LG Ultrawide. I've searched extensively but none of the suggested fixes are working for me.

```
    hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
hdmi_drive=2
disable_overscan=1

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_timings=2560 1 64 64 96 1080 1 3 10 31 0 0 1 60 0 185580000 8

config_hdmi_boost=4

max_framebuffer_width=2560
max_framebuffer_height=1280
framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1080

gpu_mem=128
arm_freq=900
gpu_freq=275
sdram_freq=500
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=400000000
avoid_pwm_pll=1
```

I've tried the following:

xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync

but when I try to add it I get:

xxx@cryptoporticus:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2 2560x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

xrandr output:

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
  2560x1080_60.00 (0x282) 230.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2720 end 2992 total 3424 skew    0 clock  67.17KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1093 total 1120           clock  59.98Hz
```

get-edid output

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LG ULTRAWIDE"
    ModelName "LG ULTRAWIDE"
    VendorName "GSM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 4 of 2014
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 800 340
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-90
    VertRefresh 56-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 240MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 12" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 185.58 2560 2624 2688 2784 1080 1083 1093 1111 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 11" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 13" 74.25 1920 2008 2052 2200 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 14" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 15" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 12"
EndSection
```

get-edid output :

Answer (score 1):

looks like your refresh (60hz) is too high and this is causing the pclk to go above the range supported by your card + cable + monitor combo.

the edid output has the modeline you need , it is Mode 0

with a bit of trial and error i generated the following modeline
using the cvt program. It is close to the Mode 0 definition as possible but in a form the you use with xrandr or in your xorg.conf

```
$ cvt 2560 1080 49.45
# 2560x1080 49.36 Hz (CVT) hsync: 54.98 kHz; pclk: 186.50 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_49.45"  186.50  2560 2712 2976 3392  1080 1083 1093 1114 -hsync +vsync
```

if that doesn't work try changing the 49.95 to use 49 to lower the pclk.

Another thing to check is the HDMI mode setting on the monitor, for resolutions above HD its worth enabling the newer HDMI modes such 1.4a or 2.0 , this could change the PreferredMode setting.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. What is the pcik?

Comment: the pcclk is the the first value in the modeline , in this case 186.50 , it represents the maximum frequency of signal your video card can put out. higher resolutions and refresh rates mean high pclk as they are all encoded into various phases of the pclk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this didn't work - the screen is still stretched so that everything appears wider than it should; I tried via xrandr and also xorg.conf. Also my monitor doesn't have the option to switch HDMI mode

Comment: it might be worth trying your monitor on a different computer to see if the graphics card doesn't support that resolution.